# How to draw non-scalable circle in SVG with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm developing a map, in Javascript using SVG to draw the lines.

I would like to add a feature where you can search for a road, and if the road is found, a circle appears on the map.

I know i can draw a circle in SVG, but my problem is that, the size of the circle should not change depending on the zoom-level. In other words the circle must have the same size at all times.
The roads on my map have this feature, all i had to do was add

```
vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
```

to the line attributes..

A line looks like this.

```
<line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke-width="3" id = 'line1' x1 = '0' y1 = '0' x2 = '0' y2 = '0' style = 'stroke:rgb(255,215,0);'/>
```

The circle looks like this.

```
<circle id = "pointCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" fill = "red"/>
```

Is it possible to define the circle as "non-scaling" somehow?

Comment: How do you zoom? If you scale the whole map, I solved this by scaling the object by the inverse of the scale, i.e. if you scale the map by a factor of `s`, you can scale the circle by `1/s`.

Comment: I zoom using SVGPan. I will try out your idea :)
http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/

Comment: Find it a bit ironic to have to draw a non-scalable circle in __Scalable__ Vector Graphic

Comment: @RuneFS I figure you are mostly joking, but consider also the commonplace need to overlay 2D "HUD"-style graphics over a 3D scene. In general, user-space labels have very different needs than complex interactive content which they may be annotating.

Answer (score 7):

It took me a while, but I finally got the math clean. This solution requires three things:

1. Include [this script](http://phrogz.net/svg/libraries/SVGPanUnscale.js) in your page (along with the SVGPan.js script), e.g.
   `<script xlink:href="SVGPanUnscale.js"></script>`
2. Identify the items you want not to scale (e.g. place them in a group with a special class or ID, or put a particular class on each element) and then tell the script how to find those items, e.g.
   `unscaleEach("g.non-scaling > *, circle.non-scaling");`
3. **Use `transform="translate(…,…)"` to place each element on the diagram, *not* `cx="…" cy="…"`.**

With just those steps, zooming and panning using SVGPan will not affect the scale (or rotation, or skew) of marked elements.

### Demo: http://phrogz.net/svg/scale-independent-elements.svg

### Library

```js
// Copyright 2012 © Gavin Kistner, !@phrogz.net
// License: http://phrogz.net/JS/_ReuseLicense.txt

// Undo the scaling to selected elements inside an SVGPan viewport
function unscaleEach(selector){
  if (!selector) selector = "g.non-scaling > *";
  window.addEventListener('mousewheel',     unzoom, false);
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', unzoom, false);
  function unzoom(evt){
    // getRoot is a global function exposed by SVGPan
    var r = getRoot(evt.target.ownerDocument);
    [].forEach.call(r.querySelectorAll(selector), unscale);
  }
}

// Counteract all transforms applied above an element.
// Apply a translation to the element to have it remain at a local position
function unscale(el){
  var svg = el.ownerSVGElement;
  var xf = el.scaleIndependentXForm;
  if (!xf){
    // Keep a single transform matrix in the stack for fighting transformations
    // Be sure to apply this transform after existing transforms (translate)
    xf = el.scaleIndependentXForm = svg.createSVGTransform();
    el.transform.baseVal.appendItem(xf);
  }
  var m = svg.getTransformToElement(el.parentNode);
  m.e = m.f = 0; // Ignore (preserve) any translations done up to this point
  xf.setMatrix(m);
}
```

### Demo Code

```svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Scale-Independent Elements</title>
  <style>
    polyline { fill:none; stroke:#000; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke; }
    circle, polygon { fill:#ff9; stroke:#f00; opacity:0.5 }
  </style>
  <g id="viewport" transform="translate(500,300)">
    <polyline points="-100,-50 50,75 100,50" />
    <g class="non-scaling">
      <circle  transform="translate(-100,-50)" r="10" />
      <polygon transform="translate(100,50)" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </g>
    <circle class="non-scaling" transform="translate(50,75)" r="10" />
  </g>
  <script xlink:href="SVGPan.js"></script>
  <script xlink:href="SVGPanUnscale.js"></script>
  <script>
    unscaleEach("g.non-scaling > *, circle.non-scaling");
  </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in opera 22.0.1471.40 (although was working like a month ago...) or IE 10. Works fine in Opera 12.17. Come to web development they said, just one platform they said, works everywhere they said...

Comment: (I should note, my own code based on unscale works in Opera 12.17, the demo itself doesn't zoom)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a fully static way of doing this, you might be able to combine non-scaling-stroke with markers to get this, since the markers can be relative to the stroke-width.

In other words, you could wrap the circles in a <marker> element and then use those markers where you need them.

```
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
    <marker id="Triangle"
      viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" 
      markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
      orient="auto">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
        <path d="M 100 100 l 200 0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" 
        marker-end="url(#Triangle)"  />
        <path d="M 100 200 l 200 0" 
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" 
        marker-end="url(#Triangle)"  />
</svg>
```

The same can also be viewed and tweaked [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vScAX/). The svg spec isn't fully explicit about what should happen in this case (since markers are not in SVG Tiny 1.2, and vector-effect isn't in SVG 1.1). My current line of thinking was that it should probably affect the size of the marker, but it seems no viewers do that at the moment (try in a viewer that supports vector-effect, e.g Opera or Chrome).

Comment: Can you give an example on how the code would look like?
For example if I wan't a circle that's always 15px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some work was done in webkit (maybe related to this bug: [320635](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=320635)) and the new transform doesn't stick around when simply appended like that

```
transform.baseVal.appendItem
```

This seems to work better. Even works in IE 10.

EDIT: Fixed the code for more general case of multiple translate transformations in the front and possible other transformations after. First matrix transformation after all translates must be reserved for unscale though.

`translate(1718.07 839.711) translate(0 0) matrix(0.287175 0 0 0.287175 0 0) rotate(45 100 100)`

```
function unscale()
{
    var xf = this.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform();
    var m = this.ownerSVGElement.getTransformToElement(this.parentNode);
    m.e = m.f = 0; // Ignore (preserve) any translations done up to this point
    xf.setMatrix(m);

    // Keep a single transform matrix in the stack for fighting transformations
    // Be sure to apply this transform after existing transforms (translate)
    var SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX = 1;
    var SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE = 2;
    var baseVal = this.transform.baseVal;
    if(baseVal.numberOfItems == 0)
        baseVal.appendItem(xf);
    else
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < baseVal.numberOfItems; ++i)
        {
            if(baseVal.getItem(i).type == SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE && i == baseVal.numberOfItems - 1)
        {
                baseVal.appendItem(xf);
            }

            if(baseVal.getItem(i).type != SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE)
            {
                if(baseVal.getItem(i).type == SVG_TRANSFORM_MATRIX)
                    baseVal.replaceItem(xf, i);
                else
                    baseVal.insertItemBefore(xf, i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
Chrome killed getTransformToElement for some reason, so the matrix needs to be retrieved manually:

```
var m = this.parentNode.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.ownerSVGElement.getScreenCTM());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's discussed [here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/track/issues/2448) and [here](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/323#issuecomment-613627346)

It looks like current browsers don't do the expected thing, so one needs to apply the inverse transform of the zoom (scale) on the contents of the `<marker>`, eg. `transorm: scaleX(5)` on the user of the `<marker>` etc. will need to be accompanied by a `transform: translate(...) scaleX(0.2)` inside the `<pattern>`, also factoring in possible `x`/`y`/`width`/`height`/`transform-origin` values inside the pattern if needed