# SVG: non-scaling-stroke inside pattern doesn't work?

Tags: svg

When using *vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"* inside a pattern, I do not get the expected result in Firefox or Chrome, though Opera works as expected...

Example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100px" width="1000px">
<defs>
    <pattern id="ticks" viewBox="0 0 12 4" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100%" width="10%">
        <path stroke="#000" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M 0 0 L 0 4 M 1 0 L 1 1 M 2 0 L 2 1 M 3 0 L 3 2 M 4 0 L 4 1 M 5 0 L 5 1 M 6 0 L 6 3 M 7 0 L 7 1 M 8 0 L 8 1 M 9 0 L 9 2 M 10 0 L 10 1 M 11 0 L 11 1" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ticks)" />
```

[Screenshot of results in Firefox, Chrome and Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9IZ9.png)

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in WebKit and Gecko? If it is a bug, is anyone aware of a workaround?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you define the stroke-width?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473328/how-to-draw-non-scalable-circle-in-svg-with-javascript/. Since patterns aren't in SVG Tiny 1.2 it's undefined how non-scaling-stroke should work there, and I don't think that SVG2 has defined that yet either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Opera to test this solution out, but it appears to have the desired result on Chrome and Firefox.

@galdre is right.  You need to define `stroke-width` (a value of `0.1` is assigned below).  Also, you're missing a closing `</svg>`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100px" width="1000px">
    <defs>
    <pattern id="ticks" viewBox="0 0 12 4" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100%" width="10%">
        <path stroke-width="0.1" stroke="#000" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M 0 0 L 0 4 M 1 0 L 1 1 M 2 0 L 2 1 M 3 0 L 3 2 M 4 0 L 4 1 M 5 0 L 5 1 M 6 0 L 6 3 M 7 0 L 7 1 M 8 0 L 8 1 M 9 0 L 9 2 M 10 0 L 10 1 M 11 0 L 11 1" />
    </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ticks)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The stroke width should be 1px, which is the default and thus redundant.

Comment: I see.  Well, the code above does appear to do what you're looking for ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Wzsw88A.png)).  I'm not sure if this behavior is the result of a bug or not.

Comment: Quite true... The above is just an example that makes failure obvious. If you change the stroke to 0.1, you are just making the failure less obvious. Even with a stroke-width of 0.1, you can still see that the stroke is being resized if you change the width to 3000px (lines too thick) or 300px (lines too thin).

Comment: You're right, but the same looks to be true for the Opera screenshot (although I can't quite confirm without having the browser installed).

Comment: Opera was rendering the border as 1px as desired, regardless of what the width was set to.

I say "was" because now that they've switched to Blink, the newest version most likely renders it just like Chrome.